# How to bind command for Xamarin forms IOS back button without ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to bind a Command for Xamarin forms IOS. I have followed  bellow code to bind command to back button. I don't want to use ViewModel.

//this code inside the constructor

```
 Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, new BackButtonBehavior
        {
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                GoBack();
            }),
        });
```

//method for go back

```
 private async Task GoBack()
    {
        bool result = await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(
            "Going Back?",
            "Are you sure you want to go back?",
            "Yes, Please!", "Nope!");

        if (result)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
        }
    }
```

The code perfectly working for Android but not for IOS. Appreciate the quick help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isnt Back button on iOS, so I would assume you cannot bind it. I'm affraid that you will have to write a method that removes the page from Navigation Stack on iOS.

Comment: i agree with @Woj theres no any back button on ios! soo what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Hi ,do you mean this code of `BackButtonBehavior` method not works in iOS ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior What is the version of Xamarin Forms used in project ?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see exact documentation for this, I think it is safe to assume that this uses `OnBackButtonPressed` API. As such it works only on Android and only if you press the operating system back button not when you press the back button in the toolbar.